# Why coroutine_handle.done cannot return correct result?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-coroutine

I'm currently learning about coroutine in c++20. I encountered a problem. Here is my code:

```
//coroutine return object definition
class ReturnObject {
public:
    struct promise_type {
        std::suspend_never initial_suspend() { return {}; }
        std::suspend_never final_suspend() noexcept { 
            return {}; 
        }
        ReturnObject get_return_object() { return ReturnObject(*this); }
        std::suspend_always yield_value(int val)
        {
            m_value = val;
            return std::suspend_always{};
        }
        void unhandled_exception() {}
        void return_void() {}
    private:
        int m_value;
    public:
        int GetValue() const { return m_value; }
    };
private:
    std::coroutine_handle<promise_type> m_handle;
public:
    decltype(m_handle) Handle() { return m_handle; }
    ReturnObject(promise_type& promise) : m_handle(std::coroutine_handle<promise_type>::from_promise(promise)){}
    int GetValue() const { return m_handle.promise().GetValue(); }
};

//range generator
ReturnObject Range(int startInc, int endInc, int step = 1)
{
    for (int i = startInc; i <= endInc; i += step)
    {
        co_yield i;
    }
}

//main function
int main()
{
    ReturnObject range = Range(1,10,3);
    while (!range.Handle().done())
    {
        std::cout << range.GetValue() << std::endl;
        range.Handle().resume();
    }
}
```

I found that the while-loop cannot quit correctly and it results in a runtime error. Could someone tell me why?

Comment: your `final_suspend` is `suspend_never`, so the coroutine self-destructs when it completes, and the handle becomes invalid. You then try to use that handle (to check its `done()`) and that is UB. `done()` [returns `true` if the coroutine is suspended at its final suspension point](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/coroutine.handle.observers#3), but your coroutine is not suspended at its final suspension point. It has executed *past* its final suspension point. You should make `final_suspend` return `suspend_always`, and then after the loop exits, manually `.destroy()` the coroutine handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `coroutine_handle` is like a raw pointer to the coroutine frame. In particular, like a raw pointer, the `coroutine_handle` does not have ownership and can become dangling if the coroutine frame goes away. That is what is happening here when `Range()` has completed its `for`-loop.

The `done()` method is particularly misleading in this regard, as the name suggests that it is able to indicate whether the `coroutine_handle` is still valid. That is *not* the case! The same is true for the `operator bool()` on the `coroutine_handle`.

The data that `done()` operates on is part of the coroutine frame and therefore when the handle becomes dangling, `done()` is also no longer functional. Instead `done()` only indicates whether the coroutine has reached its final suspension point, that is, it is currently suspended on the awaitable returned by `final_suspend`. If, as in your case, `final_suspend` does not trigger a suspension, the coroutine frame destroys itself and the `coroutine_handle` becomes dangling and must no longer be used.

Then, you may ask, why does this design allow a coroutine to destroy itself in the first place? This is indeed a peculiar design choice. In most cases, it is just not useful and your rule of thumb should be to always `suspend_always` on the `final_suspend`. In very rare cases, you may end up with a design where the coroutine is supposed to destroy itself and where the surrounding system logic ensures that it will not be accessed anymore afterwards. But this is a highly specialized and rather advanced use case, so I would not worry about it at all when learning the feature.

Comment: "why does this design allow a coroutine to destroy itself in the first place?" This is common for non-generator coroutines that produce a single result. When the coroutine finishes, it stores the result in the return object and then destroys itself (since the coroutine is no longer needed - it finished its job, namely, to produce a result and store it in the return object).